# Clearing the activity stack without firing intent for new activity

Tags: android

I want to clear the activity stack when the user comes back to the dashboard screen. To achieve only one entry point for all the links I have on the dashboard.

How to clear all the activity stacks programmatically?

I know one option of firing the Intent of dashboard activity with the `Intent.CLEAR_TASK` and `Intent.NEW_TASK` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call startActivity on the last activity you could always use

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

as a flag on that intent.

Read more about the flag [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Comment: Thanks, @snorlax, it worked for me as intended.